# How to read a numpy ndarray from a block of memory?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a block of memory that stores a 2D array of `float32` numbers.

For example, the shape is `(1000, 10)`, and what I have in memory is something like a C array with `10000` elements.

Can I turn this into a numpy array just by specifying the shape and `dtype`?

Comment: How do you access this block?  The basic constructor `ndarray` has a buffer parameter.

Comment: @hpaulj I want to avoid copying the data, so that once the array is in memory, numpy can reuse it to instantiate an array object directly.

Comment: Where is it in memory?  How do you reference it?  `ndarray` says its `buffer` must be an `object exposing buffer interface`.  Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: @hpaulj I just found out that I can simply call the `np.frombuffer` function.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `numpy` supports interpreting a buffer as a 1-D `array`.

```
import numpy as np

def load_array(data, shape):
    return np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.float32).reshape(shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading a memory-mapped array from disk involves **numpy.memmap()** function. The data type and the shape need to be specified again, as this information is not stored in the file.

Lets call the file containing data in disk : **memmapped.dat**

***import numpy as np***

***array = np.memmap('memmapped.dat', dtype=np.float32,shape=(1000, 10))***

Ref : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html and https://ipython-books.github.io/48-processing-large-numpy-arrays-with-memory-mapping/